# Make NERD Commenter prepend before spaces

Tags: vim, nerdcommenter

Is there a way to put the comment character at the very beginning of the line, before any spaces, e.g., instead of having comments inserted like this

```
// if (b != 0)
   // if (a > b) 
      // cout << a << endl;
```

it should be like this

```
// if (b != 0)
//    if (a > b) 
//       cout << a << endl;
```

The only things I see in the doc are NERDSpaceDelims and NERDRemoveExtraSpaces, which I've tried toggling and don't seem to help this issue.

Comment: You might want to consider switching to [tcomment](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim) which does this by default.

Comment: @MateuszPiotrowski Agreed and I'll mark it as such, but not sure why you gave the same answer found there before you pointed this out...

Comment: @alaferg Well, I've not tried <leader>cl before answering. I thought that the issue is much more complex. After somedays I did more research and realised that it this question is in fact a duplicate. One way or another, I've got no idea what might be wrong with your Vim configuration ...

Comment: @MateuszPiotrowski Well thanks anyway for the help. I agree that <leader>cl should work, so I guess I'll just live without it for now.

Comment: @alaferg You can try to reinstall your Vim and NERDcommenter. Or try to run NERDcommenter without your standard .vimrc file (I think that `-u` flag can load an alternative vimrc file). You can also try to look at your Vim version using `:version`. Maybe there is a some component missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use vanilla `vim`, Here we go

Select the block using `C-v`, followed by any navigation key, in your case `j`. Then `I`. This will take you `insert` mode.

Now we can use any key to insert, for your particular example, `\\`. Finalize it by <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

We should have commented block now.